# haproxy cut backendpath without removing the folder itself

Tags: haproxy

i would like to cut out a subsite from the URL at the backend location, so i tried out this:

```
http-request replace-path ^/subsite/css/(.*) /\1 if { path_beg /subsite/css/ }
```

however the CSS files are in the folder /css/ which means i unfortunately cut out that folder as well.
If i only cut the subsite out like this:

```
http-request replace-path ^/subsite/(.*) /\1 if { path_beg /subsite/ }
```

It solves the problem for accessing css files, however all the other files are not accessible
Is there a way to cut off subsite only when the request is "/subsite/css/*"?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not totally clear, but if I understood, you just need to add `/css` to the replace string.

```
http-request replace-path ^/subsite/css/(.*) /css/\1 if { path_beg /subsite/css/ }
```

For details of how PCRE works in HAProxy, see the [HAProxy docs](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/2-0r1/traffic-management/http-rewrite/).

Comment: thx for the answer, unfortunately i dont think so. As i want to to map "/subsite/css/*" to "/"

Comment: i have been to the docu, however it is very hard to understand for me :(